# Include text with a search

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button action that reads off input from a textfield when the user types something, here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)searchnickname:(id)sender{

    [theWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString: (@"*Nick:", searchText.text)];

}
```

What I need this to do, is when the user hits this button.. It puts "*Nick:" then whatever the user types after that. I need it to automatically add *Nick: before the string the user enters.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

*I hope this helps:*

```
-(IBAction)searchNickname:(id)sender {
       [theWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString: [@"*Nick:" stringByAppendingString:searchText.text]];
}
```

Comment: still no go.. seems as if it only selects "*Nick:"

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
-(IBAction)searchnickname:(id)sender{

    [theWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nick:%@",searchText.text]];

}
```

Comment: It does read "Nick:" but not the other half of the user input strings after that